# No system sounds on KDE plasma when using pipewire

Tags: linux, audio, kde, plasma5, pipewire

I'm running Debian 12 with `pipewire` installed. However the moment I remove pulseaudio and install pipewire, KDE system sounds (like volume change, critical battery alert...) no longer play. I have even tried with `pipewire-pulse`, but nothing changed.

I have installed pipewire according to the Debian documentation. Here is what I get in the logs after a while from pressing volume up/down:

```
pipewire-pulse[1572]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x557e2b3ffcb0 [libcanberra]: ERROR command:18 (PLAY_SAMPLE) tag:10 error:25 (Input/output error)
```

Comment: Have you reviewed https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire?

Comment: Yes I did. I followed the instructions to the letter.

Comment: Depending on your version of KDE, you might need to readjust phonon settings (/usr/bin/phononsettings)

Comment: @MC68020 This file does not exist.

Comment: Then under system settings > multimedia

Comment: I went to settings -> audio and moved the slider. And it works! Can you post it as answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing sound servers under linux is likely to confuse KDE-Plasma's pre-selection of the preferred devices / associated gain… for audio/video playback/recording.

**If running KDE-5 < 5.17**, resort to the *phonon* dialog app (either found under the global menu or firing `/usr/bin/phononsettings` under `konsole`)
Then reorganize the priority of the devices in the Audio Playback > Notifications list as what suits you best.

**Since phononsettings went deprecated with 5.17**, you should now resort to    kde-plasma-5 System-Settings under the Hardware / Audio category.
Options offered for you (at least a volume setting slider), stand on the rightmost window labeled Playback Streams / Notification Sounds.